# Changing VGA cable reduces resolution

Tags: xorg, display, resolution, vga

Already posted on superuser.com [here](https://superuser.com/questions/878436/changing-vga-cable-on-debian-lowers-resolution/) but thought of increasing visibility, hence reposting.

I just changed my VGA cable and Debian says my maximum resolution (in display) can only go upto 1024x768.

I have a 32inch LED monitor that supports a maximum of 1920x1440 (aka the maximum that VGA can support). However when I plug in my old cable, I do get this maximum resolution.

I thought it was an issue with the cheap $1 cable so bought a high end one but still the same problem. Now when I use Windows with this new cable—the high end one—I do get the maximum resolution but Debian/Ubuntu still refuses to go beyond 1024x768.

I have dual boot by the way and in windows this new VGA cable works like a charm.

Here are the details of the apparent technical differences (or so it seems) between the cables:

Old one: `HOTRON E246588` RU(looks like an interverted R adjoined with a U) `AWM style 20276 vw-1 80C 30V CRU AWM I/II A/B 80C 30V FT1`

New one: `AWM 2919 VW-1 80c 30V VW-1 LOW VOLTAGE COMPUTER CABLE BAILIHENG BLH:20000229`

The only technical thing I could make out from above is the older one is an AWM style 20276 cable whereas the newer one is a AWM style 2919 one. I've tried googling for AWM specs but to no avail. Looks like VGA/SVGA cabling standards are rather hazy.

Could anyone point me somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

cheap cables do not fully implement all connections to 15 pins
see this http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=12530493&postcount=16

Comment: This one might be exactly right - unconnected DDC pins disabling monitor detection, causing the X server to play it safe.